# Create a 5 by 5 matrix NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

Create the following pattern by starting from a 5 by 5 null matrix:

```
 [5 0 0 0 5]
 [5 0 0 0 5]
 [5 0 0 0 5]
 [5 5 5 5 5]]

my solution:

import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((5,5))
print(x)

result:
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

I tried to add .append so I can add 5 but id didnt work? Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Rather than start with a matrix of zeros, I would start with a matrix of 5s, that makes this problem much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a small function:

```py
import numpy as np

def create_matrix(matrixh: int, matrixw: int):

  matrix = None

  for row in range(matrixh):
    if row in [(matrixh - 1), 0]:  # Check if it's the first OR last row
      newrow = np.full(matrixw, matrixh)
    else:   # The else block handles all of the rows in the middle
      newrow = np.zeros(matrixw)
      newrow[0] = matrixw  # Set the first element to matrixw
      newrow[matrixw - 1] = matrixw. # Set the last element to matrixw

    # Add the new row to the stack
    matrix = np.vstack([matrix, newrow]) if matrix is not None else newrow

  return matrix

print(create_matrix(5,5))
print(create_matrix(6,6))
print(create_matrix(7,7))
```

output:

```
[[5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
 [5. 0. 0. 0. 5.]
 [5. 0. 0. 0. 5.]
 [5. 0. 0. 0. 5.]
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]]

[[6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6.]
 [6. 0. 0. 0. 0. 6.]
 [6. 0. 0. 0. 0. 6.]
 [6. 0. 0. 0. 0. 6.]
 [6. 0. 0. 0. 0. 6.]
 [6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6.]]

[[7. 7. 7. 7. 7. 7. 7.]
 [7. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.]
 [7. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.]
 [7. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.]
 [7. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.]
 [7. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.]
 [7. 7. 7. 7. 7. 7. 7.]]
```